# Posting a YouTube video to a Facebook Group timeline passing in *&cc_load_policy=1* does not work as expected for Facebook Mobile App

Tags: facebook, youtube, integration, query-string

I'm trying to post a YouTube video to Facebook, and this video has subtitles in Portuguese.

I want the users on the Facebook Mobile App to see the YouTube video passing along *cc_load_policy=1* and *cc_lang_pref=pt* as query string parameters so they can see the subtitles in Portuguese by default.

I tried posting:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCvLVsXC2Lo&cc_load_policy=1&cc_lang_pref=pt&hl=pt
```

to the Facebook Group timeline and then clicking on the video thumbnail on the Facebook Mobile App, to no avail. The video plays on the mobile phone, but the subtitles are turned off by default.

<strike>However, when I post the very same URL above to my user's timeline, the video and the subtitles work as expected. The posts on my timeline and on the Facebook Group timeline also work when I open them on a laptop.</strike>

I tried removing the video thumbnail image from the Facebook post too, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

YouTube was disregarding the query string parameters and using the video's <meta> tag instead.

After adding a *tag* on the YouTube video such as shown below,

[image: Screenshot of the YouTube video settings page]

the video started to display the subtitles in Portuguese as expected.

So, in a nutshell, you just have to add the following tag, `yt:cc=on`, to the list of tags for your YouTube video.